# SQL query to find a linked list parent child record from the same table

Tags: sql

I can find the first level and x level child records from the same table using inner joins. However, it is not efficient because I have to have that many inner joins for the deepest child items. Not all child are at the same level.

Do I need a view or or some sub query?

The nested child records is like a windows File Explorer where some files may be 3 levels deep and some are 5 levels deep.

For every child record there is always a parent ID.

BTW, all the child's I am trying to retrieve belongs to a parent that is the root I am looking for.

Comment: You should use recursive CTE.

Comment: I was able to build a CTE but that didn't help. I can locate all files who are under the root but I want to know the tree structure(path). For example, clients is the root record with an ID of 1. Now there are 100 client record who have a parent key (ID 1) and they each have their own ID( 100, 101, xxx). Now this client record will have X records that have parent key (101) because they belong to that client record.  These records could be categories, for example, Tax, Investment, Mortgage...etc and they each have their own Id. Then from here they could have 1 to many categories again.

Comment: I think you have an idea of the structure now. However, not clients have the same structure. 

I want to find all records and the structure(paths) of how each record is who have the parent key of ID 1.

Comment: BTW, I forgot to mention all these records are in the same table.

Comment: BTW, all these records are in the same table.

Comment: Nobody see your comments. [Edit] the question!